# Java-8 Streams: Convert List<{String,List<String>}> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a Tag class which contains a list of Items

```
class Tag {

private String tagName
private List<String> items

}
```

I have a list of Tags in which each tag a list of items

```
List<Tag> tagList =   [
                       {"tagName": "popular", "items": ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]},
                       {"tagName": "expensive" , "items":  ["Item2","Item4","Item5"]},
                       {"tagName": "mostwanted", "items":  ["Item1","Item2","Item5"]}
                      ]
```

I wan to convert this to a map which have the items as key and tagName as values.

expected output :

```
{
    "Item1" : ["popular","mostwanted"],
    "Item2" : ["popular","expensive","mostwanted"],
    "Item3" : ["popular","mostwanted"],
    "Item4" : ["popular","expensive"],
    "Item5" : ["expensive","mostwanted"]
}
```

I tried various combination of stream/faltmap/groupingBy, but I didnt get the expected output. Can you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a procedural way to go using new features from [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) such as `Map::computeIfPresent` and `Map::computeIfAbsent`, but without [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    tagList.forEach(tag -> {
        String tagName = tag.getTagName();
        tag.getItems().forEach(item -> {
            map.computeIfPresent(item, (k, v) -> { v.add(tagName); return v; });
            map.computeIfAbsent(item, k -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tagName)));
   });
});

map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

If you want to sort these items from `Item1` to `Item5`, use the different implementation:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Moreover, your expected output doesn't match as long as there is only one occurence of `Item3`:

```
Item1 [popular, mostwanted]
Item2 [popular, expensive, mostwanted]
Item3 [popular]
Item4 [popular, expensive]
Item5 [expensive, mostwanted]
```

Comment: You might have meant something simpler as `tagList.forEach(tag -> tag.getItems().forEach(item -> map.computeIfAbsent(item, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(tag.getTagName())));`...though I would have preferred `for (Tag tag : tagList) {
            for (String item : tag.getItems()) {
                map.computeIfAbsent(item, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(tag.getTagName());
            }
        }`

Comment: @Naman: You are right, I have forgotten about the return types of these methods (IMHO, the word "compute" is somehow associated with `void` in my mind). Feel free to post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can flat the `items` using `flatMap` then create pair of `item` and `tagName` using `SimpleEntry`. Then grouping by `item` using `groupingBy` and map `tagName` to get list of `tagName`

```
Map<String, List<String>> tagMap = tagList.stream()
        .flatMap(t -> t.getItems()
                       .stream()
                       .map(item -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item, t.getTagName())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getKey(),
            Collectors.mapping(m -> m.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: It's a good one! Stream API here looks very clumsy :) Moreover, I struggled to compose it.

Comment: @Nikolas When you love Stream API more then it looks nice also :)